# Unlock Motorola Droid Razr Maxx (Verizon)

Tags: sim-unlocking, motorola-droid-razr, verizon

I have a Motorola Droid Razr Maxx on Verizon in the US. I want to take it to Straight Talk, a MVNO that uses Verizon's network. I bought the Straight Talk SIM card, but I get an error that the phone needs to be unlocked.

How can I unlock the phone to use it with another provider (same CDMA network type)?

Comment: In my country (France) a MVNO that uses the same network as the operator that sold you your phone does not need the phone to be unlocked...

Answer (score 1):

Provided you bought the correct SIM card (StraightTalk provides its service using all 4 major US mobile networks - ATT, TMO, Verizon and Sprint)

from [How to Convert Verizon Wireless Phones to Straight Talk](http://science.opposingviews.com/convert-verizon-wireless-phones-straight-talk-14325.html):

> Contact Verizon Wireless. Verify your account information and explain
>   to the representative that you would like to unlock your phone for use
>   with another service. Pay your outstanding balance due and the early
>   termination fee, if applicable. Obtain an unlock code from the
>   representative.

Comment: I tried that. I called Verizon and they explained they cannot support unlocking a phone, even though I'm willing to pay the ETF and such.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the new Droid Maxx (2013 model,  MOTXT1080M), then it is already unlocked out of the box.   Just pop your Sim card in and it will work.   Just be aware that the data will be HSPA+ and not LTE.

Comment: It was purchased new in February 2012, so it's probably not the newest model. It's a Droid Razr Maxx.